# How to make heading 4 downwards: Markdown to Word

Tags: ms-word, r-markdown, markdown

Other posts deal with the problem that headings of level 4 downwards are not shown in other programs like [latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134416/level-4-heading-issue-in-r-markdown) . However, I use Markdown in combination with MS Word and wonder how I could use levels 4, 5, 6, downwards there. If I render it now, I get a simple text output.

Example for level 4 heading:

```
#### I am a heading 4
```

If there is no easy way to do that, my next step would be to mark headings with some tags and then run a word macro over it. But I would rather avoid that.

(PS: The heading in Markdown works well.)

Comment: [according to the Rmarkdown cheatsheet](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/rmarkdown-cheatsheet-2.0.pdf), you are correct with your heading 4. Are you having header problems when converting to word_document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was not the code at all. I used a reference file, and in such a reference file, all necessary headings must be added to the styles gallery. You can do it by using them at least once in the text.

Answer (score 1):

Did you leave a space between the text and the heading? Because

```
text
#### I am a heading 4
```

gives this result:

[image]

Whereas with a space between text and heading like here below

```
text

#### I am a heading 4
```

Gives this result:
[image]