# Does anyone know why my rmarkdown header cannot show succesfully in the pdfout?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

When I write:

```
#Head1  
##Head2  
###Head3  
####Head4
```

The first three headers are successfully displayed in the pdf output.
But for the  `###Head4`, it cannot separate with the next line, the next line sentence just starts at the end of the head, not automatically start a new line.

I tried to add a double space after the Head4, it still failed.

I also tried to add a blank line after Head4, but it still failed!

Could anyone help me to deal with this issue? Thanks a lot!!!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is correct. The fourth level is inline, in the same way that it is for [APA style](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/paper-format/headings). If you want something different, you could use a [different pandoc template](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#custom-templates-1).

Comment: I have tried *template: quarterly-report.tex* at the beginning, it shows "Could not find data file templates\quarterly-report.tex".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Level 4 Heading issue in R Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134416/level-4-heading-issue-in-r-markdown)

Comment: @Hannah sorry if that wasn't clear. *quarterly-report.tex* is an example of a custom template. You can search the web for custom latex templates to find one that fits your needs. It needs to go in the same folder as the .Rmd file.

Comment: @Taren Sanders
Thanks for your sharing, this helps a lot!

Comment: @Taren Sanders Thanks! I have created a new tex file in the same path as the rmd file, but it didn't run successfully.

Comment: Just for the record: I votes to close as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134416/level-4-heading-issue-in-r-markdown , unfortunately the close notice will display "off-topic" as reason because the majority voted this way .... makes no sense, but that's what the system does

Answer (score -2):

not best practice probably, but a good ol' `<br>` would probably do it.

Comment: `<br>` is a HTML command, and pdf output is handled with LaTeX, so this wouldn't work. The equivalent LaTeX command would be `\newline`.